# Concatenate features in one feature class by the unique ID

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

Is there a way to concatenate features in ArcGIS by using ArcPy, or field calculator, to produce the following output?  I am aware of [the concatenate tool that Esri created](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/07/05/concatenaterowvalues/), however it doesn't keep the Features and the Values in the same order.

I need Feature A, to line up with the appropriate Value.  And the tool also condenses multiple values.  If there are two 0's in the output, the tool will get rid of the extra ones.

[image]

After talking to Craig.  Here is the python code that I have been testing, this is from the link that he provided in the comments:  I reset the links to my personal folders, however the error that I keep receiving states, "RuntimeError: cannot open" for the link of the new_table.  When I do create a copy of the source table to be used as the new_table, and rename it as table2.dbf, it deletes the information.

```
import os  
import arcpy  
arcpy.env.workspace = r"c:\users\Desktop\test" 
table = r"c:\users\Desktop\test\GridforPython.dbf" # source_table  
new_table = r"table.dbf" # new table name + extension only  
tempTable = r"\\in_memory\temp_table"  
outPath = r"c:\users\Desktop\test" # path to output location on disk  
keyField = "ID_Input" 
valField = "Value_Input"

tableDict = {}  
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(table, tempTable)  
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [keyField, valField]) as cursor:   
    for row in cursor:  
        tableDict.setdefault(row[0], []).append(row[1])  

insertCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(os.path.join(outPath, new_table), [keyField, valField])  
for key, val in tableDict.iteritems():  
    insertCursor.insertRow((key, ', '.join(str(item) for item in val)))
```

Comment: I had a similar issue a year or so ago. Essentially, you can use arcpy and SearchCursor and InsertCursor to do what you are looking for: https://geonet.esri.com/message/101910?sr=search&searchId=6cb01bda-20a8-40b6-bc0b-107966a637e1&searchIndex=0#101910

Comment: Could you please define the input values and the desired output after the operation?  Will the "Feature" field (e.g. A,B,C,D,C) already be populated?

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking at that link now.  @Aaron, I changed the image to reflect the input and output values.

Comment: @Craig, I tried using the code from the link that you gave me, however, all it did was give me an empty table. Do you have any advice on using that code correctly?

Comment: I'm assuming you changed the keyField and valField values to match your dataset fields you are working with?

Comment: @Craig, Correct.  I get the error, "RuntimeError: cannot open" for the link of the new_table.  I had to create a preexisting copy of the dbf table.  The only other change that I made was the tempTable location.  I directed it to the same folder that contains the original dbf.

Comment: well reading back through that string in the forum it looks like I had a similar error, although its been a while since I've worked with this script. From my comments in the forum thread it looks like the code at the bottom worked for me.

Comment: @Craig, That's the odd thing.  I did use the code at the bottom, and then I copied and changed the last two rows.  Was there anything else that you had changed to get it to work?  It could have to do when I changed this variable: tempTable = r"\\in_memory\temp_table".  I changed it to the same folder of my initial data.

Comment: Now, before anyone offers an answer, is the ideal time to revise the focus of your question to be addressing the error by including a relevant Python code snippet.

Comment: @PolyGeo, Thank you for the suggestion.  I included the python code from Craig that I have been testing.

Comment: It seems odd to me that you would use an in_memory table as your output from MakeTableView so I think you should just give it a name like `"table_view"` instead.  Also, remove the `r` from in front of `r"table.dbf"` too.  Now I think you should run the code and if you receive an error include precisely what it is in your question (with the code updated to match).  Assuming we get an error we can make debugging that single error the subject of this question, and if any others are found then research/ask them separately.

Comment: @Craig Ok, I got it working.  I found out that having the python script open was locking the table. Also, through one of your other posts, I had to create table before running the script for the new_table.  Is there a way to convert the insert cursor to an update cursor?  So that I can add the data to an attribute column instead of creating new rows.

Comment: Since you were able to get the code from your original question working, would you be able to add that as an answer, that you can then self-accept.  For the next question (in your last comment) I recommend asking a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @Craig If you add it at as answer, I'll be able to accept your answer.  It turned out that I was locking it because I was trying to open the table through the mxd.

Comment: Rather than waiting for @Craig to provide an answer, it has now been a month since the last comment on this question, I think you should go ahead and provide an answer yourself.  It is also quite permissible to accept your own answer after that.

Comment: This question seemed to morph over time and no one has attempted to provide an answer so I am going to put it On Hold.  I'm not sure if the original question ended up being what was answered or something else.